# How do I center my heading?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My heading, 'sKoolTalk' is out of place and I tried a few ways to center it but didn't work. I tried using `position: absolute` and aligning it but it's not responsive. I want that heading to be like this:

[image: How it should look on all devices no matter the width.]

Here's my code:

```js
function displaySignInError() {
  var schoolName = document.getElementById('schoolNameBox').value.toLowerCase();
  switch (schoolName) {
    case 'new horizon gurukul':
      window.location = "NHGLogin.php";
      break;
    default:
      var schoolErrorMessage = document.getElementById('schoolErrorMessage');
      schoolErrorMessage.innerHTML = "Please Enter a valid school name, still if invalid schoold does not exist.";
      schoolErrorMessage.style.color = 'red';
      
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900|Droid+Sans:400,700|Josefin+Sans:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i|Oxygen:300,400,700|Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i|Ubuntu:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i');

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

#abhimanyu {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 50%;
}

#arjun {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  height: 50%;
}

#bheem {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 50%;
}

#eklavya {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: purple;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

#container {
  width: 30em;
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 30em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed; 
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#wrapper {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 30rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


#schoolSubmitButton {
  margin-top: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #fef;
  height: 2em;
  width: 10em;
}

#schoolName {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  position: fixed; 
  top: 60%; 
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

#schoolNameBox {
  height: 2em;
  border: none;
  width: 26em;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#schoolSubmitButton p {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  position: relative; 
  top: 30%; 
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -70%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -70%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -70%);
}

/*
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   padding-left: 10px;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
*/

#schoolErrorMessage {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 6em;
  color: black;
  width: 140%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
  right: 20%;
}

#schoolNameDiv {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 60%; 
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

#main-heading {
  color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 43%;
  right: 57%;
  font-size: 24px;
  z-index: 10;
}

#main-heading h2 span {
  color: orange;
}

#schoolAvatar {
  height: 9em;
  width: 9em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed; 
  top: 25%; 
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.footerHR {
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>NHG</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/resposive.css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="abhimanyu"></div>
    <div id="arjun"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="bheem"></div>
    <div id="eklavya"></div>
    <header>
            <div id="main-head">
              <!--      REMEMBER TO STYLE THE HEADING AND SIGN UP LINK        -->
              <a href="#" id="main-heading"><h2><span>sKool</span>Talk</h2></a>
            </div>
    </header>
    <section>
      <div id="container">
        <div id="wrapper">
          <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/a40bbe047e.png" alt="avatar" id="schoolAvatar" align="middle">
          <div id="schoolNameDiv">
            <div id="schoolName">
              <input type="text" name="schoolName" id="schoolNameBox" placeholder="Enter your School Name...">
              <br>
              <button type="submit" id="schoolSubmitButton" onclick="displaySignInError();">
                <p>Next</p>
              </button> 
              <br>
            </div>
            <br>
            <p id="schoolErrorMessage">School Doesn't exist? Tell your principal about our website now!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <br>
    <footer>
      <div class="footerHR">
      </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="JS/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: All your dom elements forcing to be there in your web page with 'float:left' or 'position:absolute' and that is wrong. Your nested elements need to get their parents' styles. I recommend you need to redesign and rewrite all elements.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by rewrite all the elements?

Comment: You should have use clear:both after using float or else you will get more issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I separate your heading two parts with span. Their parent element of  h2 width:100%. Children of h2 (spans) width 50%, one of 'float:left', one of 'float:right' and after that text align property set their position on the page.

```js
function displaySignInError() {
  var schoolName = document.getElementById('schoolNameBox').value.toLowerCase();
  switch (schoolName) {
    case 'new horizon gurukul':
      window.location = "NHGLogin.php";
      break;
    default:
      var schoolErrorMessage = document.getElementById('schoolErrorMessage');
      schoolErrorMessage.innerHTML = "Please Enter a valid school name, still if invalid schoold does not exist.";
      schoolErrorMessage.style.color = 'red';
      
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900|Droid+Sans:400,700|Josefin+Sans:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i|Oxygen:300,400,700|Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i|Ubuntu:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i');

body {
 margin : 0px;
  height: 100vh;
}

#abhimanyu {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 50%;
}

#arjun {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  height: 50%;
}

#bheem {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 50%;
}

#eklavya {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: purple;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

#container {
  width: 30em;
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 30em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed; 
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#wrapper {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 30rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


#schoolSubmitButton {
  margin-top: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #fef;
  height: 2em;
  width: 10em;
}

#schoolName {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  position: fixed; 
  top: 60%; 
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

#schoolNameBox {
  height: 2em;
  border: none;
  width: 26em;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#schoolSubmitButton p {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  position: relative; 
  top: 30%; 
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -70%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -70%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -70%);
}

/*
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   padding-left: 10px;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
*/

#schoolErrorMessage {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 6em;
  color: black;
  width: 140%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
  right: 20%;
}

#schoolNameDiv {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 60%; 
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

#main-heading {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 24px;
  z-index: 10;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#main-heading h2 span:first-child {
  color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
}

#main-heading h2 span:nth-child(2) {
  color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
}

#schoolAvatar {
  height: 9em;
  width: 9em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed; 
  top: 25%; 
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.footerHR {
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>NHG</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/resposive.css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="abhimanyu"></div>
    <div id="arjun"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="bheem"></div>
    <div id="eklavya"></div>
    <header>
            <div id="main-head">
              <!--      REMEMBER TO STYLE THE HEADING AND SIGN UP LINK        -->
              <a href="#" id="main-heading"><h2><span>sKool</span><span>Talk</span></h2></a>
            </div>
    </header>
    <section>
      <div id="container">
        <div id="wrapper">
          <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/a40bbe047e.png" alt="avatar" id="schoolAvatar" align="middle">
          <div id="schoolNameDiv">
            <div id="schoolName">
              <input type="text" name="schoolName" id="schoolNameBox" placeholder="Enter your School Name...">
              <br>
              <button type="submit" id="schoolSubmitButton" onclick="displaySignInError();">
                <p>Next</p>
              </button> 
              <br>
            </div>
            <br>
            <p id="schoolErrorMessage">School Doesn't exist? Tell your principal about our website now!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <br>
    <footer>
      <div class="footerHR">
      </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="JS/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is if you want your text to be exactly center!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>NHG</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/resposive.css" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900|Droid+Sans:400,700|Josefin+Sans:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i|Oxygen:300,400,700|Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i|Ubuntu:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i');
 body {
  height: 100vh;
}
#abhimanyu {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 50%;
}
#arjun {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  height: 50%;
}
#bheem {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 50%;
}
#eklavya {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: purple;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
#container {
  width: 30em;
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 30em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#wrapper {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 30rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#schoolSubmitButton {
  margin-top: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #fef;
  height: 2em;
  width: 10em;
}
#schoolName {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
#schoolNameBox {
  height: 2em;
  border: none;
  width: 26em;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#schoolSubmitButton p {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -70%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -70%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -70%);
}
/*
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   padding-left: 10px;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
*/

#schoolErrorMessage {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 6em;
  color: black;
  width: 140%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
  right: 20%;
}
#schoolNameDiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
#main-heading {
  color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 24px;
  z-index: 10;
  text-align : center;
}
#main-head{
  position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 10%;
}
#main-heading h2 span {
  color: orange;
}
#schoolAvatar {
  height: 9em;
  width: 9em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.footerHR {
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="abhimanyu"></div>
  <div id="arjun"></div>
  <br>
  <div id="bheem"></div>
  <div id="eklavya"></div>
  <header>
    <div id="main-head">
      <h2>sKool Talk</h2>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="wrapper">
        <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/a40bbe047e.png" alt="avatar" id="schoolAvatar" align="middle">
        <div id="schoolNameDiv">
          <div id="schoolName">
            <input type="text" name="schoolName" id="schoolNameBox" placeholder="Enter your School Name...">
            <br>
            <button type="submit" id="schoolSubmitButton" onclick="displaySignInError();">
              <p>Next</p>
            </button>
            <br>
          </div>
          <br>
          <p id="schoolErrorMessage">School Doesn't exist? Tell your principal about our website now!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <br>
  <footer>
    <div class="footerHR">
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="JS/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is something i think you is closer to what  you have in mind

```html
<html><head>
  <title>NHG</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/resposive.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900|Droid+Sans:400,700|Josefin+Sans:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i|Oxygen:300,400,700|Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i|Ubuntu:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i');
 body {
  height: 100vh;
}
#abhimanyu {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 50%;
  text-align: right;
}
#abhimanyu h2 {
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
    padding-right: 5px;
    color: orange;
}
#arjun {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  height: 50%;
  text-align: left;
}
#arjun h2 {
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: green;
}
#bheem {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 50%;
}
#eklavya {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: purple;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
#container {
  width: 30em;
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 30em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#wrapper {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 30rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#schoolSubmitButton {
  margin-top: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #fef;
  height: 2em;
  width: 10em;
}
#schoolName {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
#schoolNameBox {
  height: 2em;
  border: none;
  width: 26em;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#schoolSubmitButton p {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -70%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -70%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -70%);
}
/*
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   padding-left: 10px;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
*/

#schoolErrorMessage {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 6em;
  color: black;
  width: 140%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
  right: 20%;
}
#schoolNameDiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
#main-heading {
  color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 24px;
  z-index: 10;
  text-align : center;
}
#main-head{
  position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 10%;
}
#main-heading h2 span {
  color: orange;
}
#schoolAvatar {
  height: 9em;
  width: 9em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.footerHR {
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="abhimanyu">
    <h2>sKool</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="arjun">
    <h2>sKool</h2>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="bheem"></div>
  <div id="eklavya"></div>
  <section>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="wrapper">
        <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/a40bbe047e.png" alt="avatar" id="schoolAvatar" align="middle">
        <div id="schoolNameDiv">
          <div id="schoolName">
            <input type="text" name="schoolName" id="schoolNameBox" placeholder="Enter your School Name...">
            <br>
            <button type="submit" id="schoolSubmitButton" onclick="displaySignInError();">
              <p>Next</p>
            </button>
            <br>
          </div>
          <br>
          <p id="schoolErrorMessage">School Doesn't exist? Tell your principal about our website now!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <br>
  <footer>
    <div class="footerHR">
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="JS/script.js"></script>


</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of `position: absolute;`  try `text-align : center;`**  on `#text-heading`

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
#main-heading {
  color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 24px;
  z-index: 30;
  position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
}
```

```js
function displaySignInError() {
  var schoolName = document.getElementById('schoolNameBox').value.toLowerCase();
  switch (schoolName) {
    case 'new horizon gurukul':
      window.location = "NHGLogin.php";
      break;
    default:
      var schoolErrorMessage = document.getElementById('schoolErrorMessage');
      schoolErrorMessage.innerHTML = "Please Enter a valid school name, still if invalid schoold does not exist.";
      schoolErrorMessage.style.color = 'red';
      
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900|Droid+Sans:400,700|Josefin+Sans:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i|Oxygen:300,400,700|Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i|Ubuntu:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i');

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

#abhimanyu {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 50%;
}

#arjun {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  height: 50%;
}

#bheem {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 50%;
}

#eklavya {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: purple;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

#container {
  width: 30em;
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 30em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed; 
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#wrapper {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 30rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


#schoolSubmitButton {
  margin-top: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #fef;
  height: 2em;
  width: 10em;
}

#schoolName {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  position: fixed; 
  top: 60%; 
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

#schoolNameBox {
  height: 2em;
  border: none;
  width: 26em;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#schoolSubmitButton p {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  position: relative; 
  top: 30%; 
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -70%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -70%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -70%);
}

/*
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   padding-left: 10px;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
*/

#schoolErrorMessage {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 6em;
  color: black;
  width: 140%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
  right: 20%;
}

#schoolNameDiv {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 60%; 
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}


#main-heading {
  color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 24px;
  z-index: 30;
  position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
}

#main-heading h2 span {
  color: orange;
}

#schoolAvatar {
  height: 9em;
  width: 9em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed; 
  top: 25%; 
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.footerHR {
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>NHG</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/resposive.css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
            <div id="main-head">
              <!--      REMEMBER TO STYLE THE HEADING AND SIGN UP LINK        -->
              <a href="#" id="main-heading"><h2><span>sKool</span>Talk</h2></a>
            </div>
    </header>
    <div id="abhimanyu"></div>
    <div id="arjun"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="bheem"></div>
    <div id="eklavya"></div>
    <section>
      <div id="container">
        <div id="wrapper">
          <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/a40bbe047e.png" alt="avatar" id="schoolAvatar" align="middle">
          <div id="schoolNameDiv">
            <div id="schoolName">
              <input type="text" name="schoolName" id="schoolNameBox" placeholder="Enter your School Name...">
              <br>
              <button type="submit" id="schoolSubmitButton" onclick="displaySignInError();">
                <p>Next</p>
              </button> 
              <br>
            </div>
            <br>
            <p id="schoolErrorMessage">School Doesn't exist? Tell your principal about our website now!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <br>
    <footer>
      <div class="footerHR">
      </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="JS/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

give `#main-head` fixed width and :

```
#main-head {
position :absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
}
```

OR

```
#main-head {
width:100px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```